# NotSupportedException in FSharp query with join groupBy and sortBy

Tags: f#

I have this query (using Linq2Sql type provider):

```
let q = query {
  for zj in db.ZAJEZD do
  join zr in db.ZARIZENI on (zj.ZARIZENI = zr.ZARIZENI1)
  where (zj.AKCE = ac)
  groupBy zj.ZARIZENI into gZj
  sortBy gZj.Key
  select gZj.Key
}
```

In the runtime I get NotSupportedException:

```
Additional information: The member 'System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,System.Tuple`2[Web.DataLayer.Data+dbSchema+ServiceTypes+ZAJEZD,Web.DataLayer.Data+dbSchema+ServiceTypes+ZARIZENI]].Key' has no supported translation to SQL.
```

When I remove the sortBy clause it works well. The Key is of type string. So where could be problem to translate it to sql?

By the way, how to write join with composite key?

Thanks

Comment: Often using `groupValBy` instead of `groupBy` will result in more C#-like queries, which might be better supported by the query provider. You might try something like `groupValBy zj zj.ZARIZENI into gZj`.